# Python- Maximum consecutive count of each value in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count

Given a 1-d numpy array, aim to count the maximum number of a specific consecutive value, for example, given an array `arr`:

```
arr=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,2,4,4])
```

I would like to return the number of max consecutive value of each number. The result is a 2-d array, and the first column is each number, the second column is the maximum consecutive count of each number.

```
result=np.array([[1,3],[2,2],[3,1],[4,5]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite easy to do with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
s = pd.Series(arr)
out = (s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum(), sort=False) # group consecutive values
        .agg({'first', 'size'})                        # get value and count
        .groupby('first', sort=False)['size'].max()    # max count per value
        .reset_index().to_numpy()                      # back to numpy
      )
```

With pure [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) it's a bit more complex:

```
arr = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,2,4,4])

# identify the consecutive values
idx = np.nonzero(np.diff(arr))[0]
# array([ 2,  4,  5, 10, 11])

# get single value of consecutive ones
i = np.r_[arr[idx], arr[-1]]
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4])

# count the number of replicates
n = np.diff(np.r_[0, idx+1, arr.shape[0]])
# array([3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2])

# sort by value and count
order = np.lexsort([n, i])
# array([0, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3])

i2 = i[order]
# array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])

m = np.r_[np.diff(i2)!=0, True]
# array([ True, False,  True,  True, False,  True])

# combine
out = np.vstack([i2[m], n[order][m]]).T
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [4, 5]])
```

Using pure [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

out = {}
for k, g in groupby(arr):
    out[k] = max(out.get(k, -1), len(list(g)))

out = list(out.items())
```

Output: `[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 5)]`

##### comparison of timings

Using a random array as input (`np.random.randint(1, 5, size=N)`).

[image]

Comment: Which solution is faster?

Comment: @pts I haven't tested it and it will depend on the total size and the number/size of groups. I'll try to run some timings but if I had to bet I'd say numpy < python < pandas for the running time on large arrays.

Comment: Very interesting benchmark graph, thank you! FYI both axes are logarithmic.

Comment: @pts if you look closely, the numpy/pandas seem to asymptotically get closer to python. I believe this is because I used a fixed number of values (1-4), thus the number of groups also seems to have an effect. The initial flat lines for numpy/pandas on small lengths are due to the overhead of using those libraries.

Comment: The time used by *import* should be excluded.

Comment: @pts It is excluded, this is the intrinsic time of using library functions, doing something on an array/Series of 10 items is often less efficient than looping over a list ;)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through each value and keep a running count of how many consecutive values. If the value changes, update the max count if the previous running count is higher, then reset the running count to 1. Max count is stored using a defaultdict, then converted to an array.

```
from collections import defaultdict

arr=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,2,4,4])

prev = None
max_consecutive_count = defaultdict(int)
running_count = 0

for val in arr:
    if val == prev or not prev:
        running_count += 1
    else:
        if running_count > max_consecutive_count[prev]:
            max_consecutive_count[prev] = running_count
        running_count = 1
    
    prev = val
else:
    if running_count > max_consecutive_count[val]:
        max_consecutive_count[val] = running_count
    
max_consecutive_count_arr = [[k,v] for k,v in max_consecutive_count.items()]
```